# ReferenceError: AudioContext is not defined in Angular service

Tags: angular, audiocontext, browser-api

In my Angular service, I have defined [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/AudioContext), like so:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AudioService {
    private context = new AudioContext();

    ...
}
```

At **compile** time, Angular throws:

> ReferenceError: AudioContext is not defined

But I can do it from the developer console without complaint (this works):

```js
const context = new AudioContext();
```

It appears that quite a lot (possibly all) of the dom APIs don't seem to be available at compile-time; for example, I tried `new Image()` and `new XMLHttpRequest()`

For reference, I'm using:

- Chrome 122
- Angular 17

My `tsconfig.json` file lists the following libs:

```json
{
  "lib": [
    "ES2022",
    "dom"
  ]
}
```

How do I get Angular to play nicely with Browser APIs?

Comment: Does the problem persist even if you create a new project?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem so it might be some environment issue

Comment: @LucaRegazzi as per my comment below, the issue was that SSR and Prerendering were enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're are probably running your app with SSR enabled.

SSR is run in a node environment that doesn't support browser APIs.

If you need to run browser code, you can wrap it with

```
afterNextRender(() => {
  const ctx = new AudioContext();
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Looks like that was the issue, so I've turned ssr and prerender off in the config and it's working now.